# Multiple tab sections on one page

Tags: javascript, jquery, bourbon, neat

I am using the following code for some responsive tabs on my site:

HTML

```
div class="vertical-tabs-container">
  <div class="vertical-tabs">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="js-vertical-tab vertical-tab is-active" rel="tab1">Item 1</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="js-vertical-tab vertical-tab" rel="tab2">Item 2</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="js-vertical-tab vertical-tab" rel="tab3">Item 3</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="js-vertical-tab vertical-tab" rel="tab4">Item 4</a>
  </div>

  <div class="vertical-tab-content-container">
    <a href="" class="js-vertical-tab-accordion-heading vertical-tab-accordion-heading is-active" rel="tab1">Item 1</a>
    <div id="tab1" class="js-vertical-tab-content vertical-tab-content">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras tincidunt pellentesque lorem, id suscipit dolor rutrum id. Morbi facilisis porta volutpat. Fusce adipiscing, mauris quis congue tincidunt, sapien purus suscipit odio, quis dictum odio tortor in sem. Ut sit amet libero nec orci mattis fringilla. Praesent eu ipsum in sapien tincidunt molestie sed ut magna. Nam accumsan dui at orci rhoncus pharetra tincidunt elit ullamcorper. Sed ac mauris ipsum. Nullam imperdiet sapien id purus pretium id aliquam mi ullamcorper.</p>
    </div>

    <a href="" class="js-vertical-tab-accordion-heading vertical-tab-accordion-heading" rel="tab2">Item 2</a>
    <div id="tab2" class="js-vertical-tab-content vertical-tab-content">
      <p>Ut laoreet augue et neque pretium non sagittis nibh pulvinar. Etiam ornare tincidunt orci quis ultrices. Pellentesque ac sapien ac purus gravida ullamcorper. Duis rhoncus sodales lacus, vitae adipiscing tellus pharetra sed. Praesent bibendum.</p>
    </div>

    <a href="" class="js-vertical-tab-accordion-heading vertical-tab-accordion-heading" rel="tab3">Item 3</a>
    <div id="tab3" class="js-vertical-tab-content vertical-tab-content">
      <p>Donec mattis mauris gravida metus laoreet non rutrum sem viverra. Aenean nibh libero, viverra vel vestibulum in, porttitor ut sapien. Phasellus tempor lorem id justo ornare tincidunt. Nulla faucibus, purus eu placerat fermentum, velit mi iaculis nunc, bibendum tincidunt ipsum justo eu mauris. Nulla facilisi. Vestibulum vel lectus ac purus tempus suscipit nec sit amet eros. Nullam fringilla, enim eu lobortis dapibus, quam magna tincidunt nibh, sit amet imperdiet dolor justo congue turpis.</p>
    </div>

    <a href="" class="js-vertical-tab-accordion-heading vertical-tab-accordion-heading" rel="tab4">Item 4</a>
    <div id="tab4" class="js-vertical-tab-content vertical-tab-content">
      <p>Sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Phasellus dui urna, mollis vel suscipit in, pharetra at ligula. Pellentesque a est vel est fermentum pellentesque sed sit amet dolor. Nunc in dapibus nibh. Aliquam erat volutpat. Phasellus vel dui sed nibh iaculis convallis id sit amet urna. Proin nec tellus quis justo consequat accumsan. Vivamus turpis enim, auctor eget placerat eget, aliquam ut sapien.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

SCSS (Using Bourbon and Neat)

```
.vertical-tabs-container {
  $large-screen: em(640) !default;
  $vertical-tabs-height: em(100);

  @include clearfix;

  .vertical-tabs {
    display: none;

    @include media($large-screen) {
      display: inline;
      float: left;
      height: $vertical-tabs-height;
      width: 20%;
    }
  }

  .vertical-tab {
    @include media($large-screen) {
      display: block;

      &.is-active {
        color: #ff0000;
      }
    }
  }

  .vertical-tab-content-container {
    display: block;

    @include media($large-screen) {
      @include size(80% $vertical-tabs-height);
      display: inline-block;
    }
  }

  .vertical-tab-content {
    @include media($large-screen) {
      display: none;
    }
  }

  .vertical-tab-accordion-heading {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;

    @include media($large-screen) {
      display: none;
    }
  }
}
```

JQUERY

```
$(".js-vertical-tab-content").hide();
$(".js-vertical-tab-content:first").show();

/* if in tab mode */
$(".js-vertical-tab").click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  $(".js-vertical-tab-content").hide();
  var activeTab = $(this).attr("rel");
  $("#"+activeTab).show();

  $(".js-vertical-tab").removeClass("is-active");
  $(this).addClass("is-active");

  $(".js-vertical-tab-accordion-heading").removeClass("is-active");
  $(".js-vertical-tab-accordion-heading[rel^='"+activeTab+"']").addClass("is-active");
});

/* if in accordion mode */
$(".js-vertical-tab-accordion-heading").click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  $(".js-vertical-tab-content").hide();
  var accordionActiveTab = $(this).attr("rel");
  $("#"+accordionActiveTab).show();

  $(".js-vertical-tab-accordion-heading").removeClass("is-active");
  $(this).addClass("is-active");

  $(".js-vertical-tab").removeClass("is-active");
  $(".js-vertical-tab[rel^='"+accordionActiveTab+"']").addClass("is-active");
});
```

My issue is currently when I have more than one tab section on my page they are not working independently. I need to adjust the javascript so it makes each one work on it's own without interfering with any other. Ideally this would be without adjusting the HTML. I have tried a couple of approaches with no success so have reverted back to my original code for this question.

Answer (score 1):

The best approach to do that is with a [jQuery plugin](https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/).

But with your same code, if you want to resolve it easily, put all your `jQuery` code inside a `function` and select the elements guided by a selector sent to that function. An example code to guide you:

**HTML Code**

```
<div id="item1">
    <div class="interactive"></div>
</div>

<div id="item2">
    <div class="interactive"></div>
</div>
```

**jQuery Code**

```
function applyEvent(id){

    var element = $("div#" + id);

    element.find("div.interactive").on("click", function(){

        alert("div inside #" + id + " clicked");

    });

}

//---Apply the events to each div
applyEvent("item1");
applyEvent("item2");
```

Here you have a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/elchininet/6vghsnv5/) with your tabs duplicated.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I have got this to work. However this won't quite be suitable for me as the tab sections are CMS generated, so there could be any number of them. Is there a way for the javascript to work regardless of the number of elements?

Comment: Yes is there, `jQuery` have a powerful system of selectors. Put an example of your code with multiple tabs automatically generated and I show you how to select them and apply your code.

Comment: Thanks! Here is a link to a Codepen with an example of how the HTML would output, with my original SCSS and jQuery. Thanks so much for your help. http://codepen.io/mikehdesign/pen/jWYboG

Comment: Hi @MikeHarrison. Sorry for the late reply. I have been occupied in the last weeks. Here you have an example with the same technique that I've mentioned in my answer. Only do a [jQuery caching](https://ttmm.io/tech/selector-caching-jquery/) instead searching all the time like I done. Here you have [a fork of your code](http://codepen.io/elchininet/pen/XXLboO).